# Question falsely closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202284/are-there-any-female-dwarves-and-if-not-how-do-they-reproduce) about Tolkien's mythology has been falsely closed as a duplicate of [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28104/why-didnt-the-dwarf-women-have-beards-in-the-hobbit-an-unexpected-journey) about one of Peter Jackson's movies.

As a Peter Jackson movie is not part of the mythology that Tolkien developed in his writings, it cannot be a duplicate.

Please undo the closure.

Comment: Morgan's answer on the dupe addresses the books as well;  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/35064/20774

Comment: @Valorum That doesn't make the *question* a duplicate. Rather, it means that part of the answer deviates from the topic of the question. If a duplicate question is one that has been answered in an aside to another question, then that should be made clear in the definition of duplicate given in help pages and elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The question should be a duplicate:** the issue of female dwarves in Tolkien's legendarium has been discussed a lot on this site already. When I first saw it, I was going to dupehammer it closed, but the best fits I found were [Is the theory that dwarf women look like dwarf men limited to the works of Tolkien?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27076/31394) and [Did Tolkien originate the idea of dwarven women as being visually indistinguishable from dwarven men?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27084/31394) which aren't great choices since they aren't *directly* asking about Tolkien's legendarium.

As for the question that it *was* eventually closed as a duplicate of, [Why didn't the dwarf women have beards in The Hobbit - An Unexpected Journey?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28104/31394): although the title refers only to Jackson films, the question body mentions "*It's also stated by Tolkien in appendix A to The Lord of the Rings that female dwarves appear identical to males*" which resolves your question. Unfortunately, the top answer is film-relevant only and you need to scroll down to the second answer to find anything about Tolkien's works.

Fortunately, **I managed to find a better duplicate target**: [Who was the first female dwarf identified by name in the Hobbit/LOTR saga?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46189/31394), where both the question and the top answer are directly relevant to and almost the same as the recently-closed duplicate. I've edited the duplicate target to point to this one instead.

Comment: The only issue remaining now is that we generally dupe-close not only based on age but also the quality of the Q&A ... so I wonder if Major Stackings's question should be a dupe of the new one based on the better answer there ...

Comment: I agree that in this case – that is, with many questions "asking around" the same topic already – a new question really doesn't make much sense. I find Jeff Atwoods blog post about duplicates really helpful in not going too far with closing near-duplicates, though: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/